# How to hide particular Excel Sheets using c sharp VSTO Code?

Tags: excel, vsto

In my Vsto Excel project, i want to hide few sheets of my Excel using vsto code ?
how i can Hide any particular sheet i.e using its name or sheet No. ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets assume name of the excel is  **MySheet**.

To hide it, use

```
((Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisWorkbook.Sheets["MySheet"]).Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetHidden;
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. For crying out loud, they couldn't just have a visible property huh? :/